# Firebase retrieving data from two tables null error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new on firebase and i am facing some troubles.

```
mDatabase.child(idUsuario).child("fotos").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        idFoto = dataSnapshot.child("fotoId").getValue().toString();

        mDatabase.child("fotos/"+idFoto).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                idFotoStorage = dataSnapshot.child("idfoto").getValue().toString();
                System.out.println("The foto id is " + idFotoStorage);
```

First I get idFoto value from one table (This works).
Then I try to make another search using that value, my problem is that `idFotoStorage` is always null.

Comment: can u post a screenshot of the JSON structure from firebase.

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot, post the actual JSON as text please. You can easily get this by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.